# Технология для пользовательского вещания потокового видео с веб-камеры

Tags: node.js, php, видео, потоки-данных

Задача стоит в создании пользовательского вещания потокового видео с веб-камеры.
Где-то на хабре встречал давно статьи о какой-то технологии, забыл название...
Что сейчас использую разработчики для этого?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Google Hangouts! : ))

Серьезно - это бесплатно; вещание через YouTube, сможет смотреть любая аудитория; запись потом есть. Т.е. провести онлайн мероприятие - надежно и просто.

Comment: Для корпоратива использовал wowza media player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRtc попробуйте

Comment: Точно - оно самое. Спасибо!